# Bash does not continue execution

Tags: bash, sed, cut

I am parsing the result of an extracted string. My problem is the execution stops after the first element was processed.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCAN_RESULT=$(arp-scan --ignoredups --interface=$1 --localnet)
HEADER_REMOVED=$(echo "$SCAN_RESULT" | sed '1,2d')
NO_HEADER_LINE_COUNT=$(echo "$HEADER_REMOVED" | wc -l)
CAPTURED_DEVICE_INFO=$(echo "$HEADER_REMOVED" | sed $(expr $NO_HEADER_LINE_COUNT - 2),"$NO_HEADER_LINE_COUNT"d)
DATA=$(echo "$CAPTURED_DEVICE_INFO" | sed 's/[\t]/;/g')

DATA_LINE_COUNT=$(echo "$DATA" | wc -l)

echo -n '['
for ((i=0; i<$DATA_LINE_COUNT; i++))  # stops execution after 1st cycle
do
    EXTRACTED_DATA=$(echo "$DATA" | sed $(expr "$i" + 1)'!d')
    echo -n '{'
    COMMA_INNER=''
    for i in {1..3}
    do
        echo -n "$COMMA_INNER"      
        case $i in
            1) echo -n '"ip":' ;;
            2) echo -n '"mac":' ;;
            3) echo -n '"manufacturer":' ;;
        esac
        echo -n '"'
        echo -n $(echo $EXTRACTED_DATA | cut -d ';' -f$i)
        echo -n '"'
        COMMA_INNER=','
    done
    echo -n '}'
done
echo -n ']'
```

This is the output string from the arp-scan:

```
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 16 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.0.1     20:aa:4b:c0:22:78       (Unknown)
192.168.0.5     48:5b:39:a0:60:ba       ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
192.168.0.7     04:7d:7b:7d:c4:e9       (Unknown)

5 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 16 hosts scanned in 0.819 seconds (19.54 hosts/sec). 3 responded
```

This is the string(from arp-scan) I would like to be processed and echoed as JSON

```
192.168.0.1     20:aa:4b:c0:22:78       (Unknown)
192.168.0.5     48:5b:39:a0:60:ba       ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
192.168.0.7     04:7d:7b:7d:c4:e9       (Unknown)
```

Here is the sample output:

```
[{"ip":"192.168.0.1","mac":"20:aa:4b:c0:22:78","manufacturer":"(Unknown)"}]
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't know sed, but I think you can do this a lot easier with awk

Comment: This would be much easier in a language like Python, Perl, Ruby, or something with a proper JSON library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arp-scan --ignoredups --interface=$1 --localnet | {
  read; read    # Discard the first two header lines
  printf "["
  comma=''
  while read ip mac manufacturer; do
    printf '%s{"ip":"%s", "mac":"%s", "manufacturer":"%s"},' "$comma" "$ip" "$mac" "$manufactuer"
    comma=','
  done
  printf "]\n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll just modify some parts to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

- the same variable (`i`) for both loops and
- the wrong delimiter when splitting the line with `cut` (use `' '` instead of `';'`).

However, chepner's solution should be much better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (a big *if*, it's highly unclear), this will do it:

```
sed '1,2d;s/^/[{"ip":"/;s/  */","mac":"/;s/  */","manufacturer":"/;s/$/"}]/'
```